# Hosting a domain name bought via Squarespace on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, squarespace, domain-name, custom-domain

TL;DR: I believe I set up my Squarespace domain to be hosted on AWS Route 53 correctly but it does not work when I try to access it online (it just keeps trying to load the page but cannot, although my actual AWS website works via the AWS given link)

I have an AWS environment that has an application which is my personal website, a very simple django app. I bought a domain name on Squarespace (I'll refer to it as example.com), and i would like to be able to go to Google and type in example.com and have it load my website. So basically as I understand it my domain name is example.com, the domain registrar is Squarespace, and the domain will be hosted on AWS.

I understand it that you have to do domain hosting on AWS with Route 53. To start I made a hosted zone on AWS called example.com (the same name as the domain I bought on Squarespace), found the 4 nameservers from that, and added them custom nameservers in the Squarespace domain panel. No other changes were made (should i add DNS records there, or nameserver registration? The support agent said no but they didn't seem like an expert)

Next I went to the AWS and associated my elastic IP address with my environment. I then went to hosted zones and added in an A record: The record name is example.com (same as the domain I bought), Type: A, Routing policy: simple, Alias: no, and for Value I put the Elastic IP address that was associated with my environment from before

I waited several (4) days but still there is no result, so it is not an issue with DNS propagation or propagation within the AWS domain system. Furthermore, I tried the nslookup command in terminal on both the domain name example.com and my given elastic beanstalk url that I currently use to access the website (I'll refer to it as eb.elasticbeanstalk.com ), and they give different results for the non-authoritative answer Address; example.com gives the same IP address as my elastic IP but the eb.elasticbeanstalk.com gives something else, I assume it is one of the non elastic IP addresses that AWS says they switch between:

```
jack@10-17-22-222 ~ % nslookup example.com
Server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: example
Address: [my elastic IP]
```

```
jack@10-17-22-222 ~ % nslookup eb.elasticbeanstalk.com
Server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
Name: eb.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: [not my elastic IP]
Name: eb.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: [also not my elastic IP but not the same as the one above]
```

Anyway I've been stuck on this problem for literal weeks and am running out of ideas. I read a lot of the documentation but there's so much AWS specific jargon that I find that I am misunderstanding a lot of it. If anyone has more experience in this matter and has any suggestions, or if you noticed a mistake in the way i configured things above, could you please let me know what to change?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/